# Adding filter to the_content() on Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins

I'm trying to edit every single post using my Plugin, but when I do:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 20);

function my_the_content_filter($content)
{
    $content = 'a';

    // Returns the content.
    return $content;
}
```

There isn't any changes on my post. My single.php is using the_content().
Any idea what is happening?.

Comment: what you want to do actually ?

Comment: Code looks fine, try changing the priority to 10, or 5, or 1

Comment: Just change the whole content to 'a' (string).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function to change the content of the post.

```
// Update post 37
  $my_post = array(
      'ID'           => 37,
      'post_content' => 'a'
  );

// Update the post into the database
  wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: I don't want to actually change the content on my DB, only part of the content show on single-post using a replace.